# Rehabilitating leg warmers

Tags: clothes, clothing-care

I have a pair of leg warmers, purchased from Performance Bicycle some years ago. They're still in decent shape, but the rubber or silicone layer at the top that holds them up has thinned. The warmers tend to slide down my leg these days.

Is there a way to re-create the layer that's meant to grip them to my legs?

Comment: Maybe McNett Aquasure would work, it feels similar to the silicone strips. And make sure to put your bicycling shorts over the leg warmers, not the other way around.

Comment: There may be no economical way to restore that silicone grip tape. However, bibs often come with matching silicone grippers on the hem of the thighs to help grip leg warmers. Are you using such a pair?

Comment: Has the silicon gripper layer failed/disintegrated ?  Or has it stretched and providing less "squeeze" ?  You may be able to sew in a "tuck" to remove extra material.  I've done this with arm warmers that were too big for my noodley-cyclist arms.

Comment: I gave up on leg warmers.  On days I have to deal with a large temperature swing and start out too cold to just tough it out in bib shorts, I'll wear knickers and long, heavy wool socks.  When it gets warm I just shove the socks down around my ankles.

Comment: maybe you could try sewing a band of elastic material around the leg warmers (such that there is aband of elastomer material around your leg holding the warmers up).

Answer (score 1):

This stuff is not expensive.  Simply unpick the stitching, and replace it.

The hardest thing will be doing the stitching in a way that will stretch, because a plain straight stitch will not work.  A fancy modern sewing machine can do these stitches, as can an overlocker.

Example pricing seems to range from a few dolleurosuid to tens of them.  It gets cheaper in larger lengths, with 50 metres being under $1 / metre.

https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-silicone-gripper-elastic.html  for example.  Keywords here are "silicon grip elastic"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work but it might be worth a  try. In the hardware/tool department of your local hardware store look for "Grip" or "Plasti-dip". It comes in a container about the same size as a soda/pop/cola can. Its' primary purpose is to form an air curable plastic cover for tool handles like pliers and wire cutters. I don't see why you couldn't brush or smear some onto the top bands and allow. it to cure. It can be thinned but requires some naptha, xylene or tolulene but the toxicity issues may not make thinning worth the health risks.

Comment: I've used this stuff, and its not very stretchy.  So the leg band would be harder to put on.  Might help if it was in dabs not continuous.

Answer (score -3):

The most important part of the leg warmer IS THE silicon that grips to keep them in place.

Time to replace the whole leg warmer.

Comment: The question is about reconditioning the grip strip - could you use [edit] to focus on that ?

Comment: It feels particularly wasteful to throw away an item just because one part of it is worn.  OP is asking about rehabbing the leg warmers, and while replacing them will indeed provide a working item, that may not be in-budget, and is certainly inefficient.  I'm tempted to delete this as not-an-answer, but it does solve the problem albeit in an inefficient way, like replacing tubes instead of learning to patch punctures.